# How can I join 3 SQL tables and return latest current date and status?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:
I'm trying to write a SQL query that joins all 3 tables to return the First and Last Name from Table A, the Status of 1 where there is no 2 logged afterwards and the LogDate (Only want the current day) from table C.

TableA:

```
UserID | FirstN | LastN |
-------------------------
2324   | John   | Doe   |
2034   | Jane   | Doe   |
2946   | Mike   | Blank |
```

TableB:

```
ViewID | UserID | 
-----------------
2315   | 2324   | 
8956   | 2034   | 
6587   | 2946   |
```

TableC:

```
ViewID | LogDate                 | Status |
-------------------------------------------
2315   | 2017-02-14 11:03:47.000 | 1      |
2315   | 2017-02-14 10:14:47.000 | 2      |
2315   | 2017-02-14 10:00:19.000 | 1      |
```

In the Status column of TableC, 1 means currently viewing and 2 means done viewing, with LogDate giving the date and time of the Status.

TableA and TableB have the UserID column in common.  TableB and TableC have the ViewID column in common.

A person can view a document multiple times in one day so it's possible that the ViewID shows up multiple times in one day with different statuses so I want to return only the most current Status 1 where the user has not finished viewing the document on the current day.

So if you look at TableC, you can see that the same user viewed the document at     ***2017-02-14 10:00:19.000***, then finished at ***2017-02-14 10:14:47.000***, and then viewed again at ***2017-02-14 11:03:47.000***.  So in this example, I only want the user viewing the document at ***2017-02-14 11:03:47.000*** because the user has not finished viewing (status did not change to 2 again yet).

I hope I'm making sense in explaining what i'm trying to accomplish....

So, this is what I tried but haven't completely gotten what I want.  I can't figure out how to join TableA to get the first and last name and also, stuck trying to get only the current Status of 1 if the user has not finished viewing.  It's returning every status of 1 throughout the day.

```
SELECT 
    tblb.ViewID,
    tblc.LogDate, tblc.Status,
    tblb.UserID
FROM 
    TableB AS tblb
INNER JOIN 
    TableC AS tblc ON tblb.ViewID =  tblc.ViewID
WHERE
    LogDate >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
    AND LogDate < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
    AND Status = 1
```

Comment: Is the viewid in table b the document id, or the session id? Meaning, if I viewed the same document twice, will I have two identical viewid's for both  viewings?

Comment: I think it would help you if you keep the LogID when a user opens the doc, and then use it to populate the Log Entry for when the user closes it. You could add another nullable column for LogOpenID to associate the close log record with the open log record.

Comment: Yes, the ViewID would remain the same...it's more of a session id and not document id

Comment: I added a column LogID in TableC which increments as a change is made to Status column...maybe this can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  it's impossible to have sequence of statuses like (1,1,2) i.e. to open the same doc without closing it first, we need only the last status. So we can figure out the users having open docs and [left] join it to TableA.

```
SELECT ta.FirstN, ta.LastN, tbc.*
FROM
    (SELECT UserID, tblc.*
    FROM TableB AS tblb
    CROSS APPLY(
       SELECT TOP(1) * 
       FROM TableC AS tblc 
       WHERE tblb.ViewID =  tblc.ViewID
         AND LogDate >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
         AND LogDate < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
       ORDER BY LogDate DESC
       ) tblc
    WHERE Status = 1
    ) tbc
 LEFT JOIN TableA ta ON ta.UserID = tbc.UserID;
```

Comment: I would still need the first and last name from TableA

Comment: Thanks, Serg.  That did it.